# MTD Erase Block Size of zero for SRAM

Tags: embedded, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

**Refined Question**

How do read and write text information from a MTD SRAM device with erase block size zero?

Notes:

1. I am using the [23K256](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/mtd/devices/mchp23k256.c) Driver
2. Attempts to use MTD-Util tools have failed because `libmtd` cannot handle a erase block size of zero
3. Attempts to artificially add an erase block size has also failed (see below)
4. Attempts to use `echo >` and `cat` to the `mtdblock` have only produced garbage

**Original**
I am attempting to read and write to a SRAM chip connected to a ARM processor running Linux. I do not care if i interface with the SRAM like a file, serial device or memory partition. The existing device driver for the SRAM chip registers the device as a MTD. I verified this by checking `/proc/mtd`:

```
~# cat /proc/mtd
dev:    size   erasesize  name
mtd0: 00020000 00000000 "spi1.0"
```

I found a tutorial to format the MTD using MTD utils. The problem I am experiencing is that I cannot interface with the SRAM/MTD device because all the user-space MTD/UBI/JFF2 tools crash when looking at this device, IE:

```
~# mtdinfo
Count of MTD devices:           1
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

This exception appears to be occurring because all the MTD utilities use libmtd. The `mtd_get_dev_info1` function in libmtd divides by the erase block size and in my case the erase block size is zero.

```
mtd->eb_cnt = mtd->size / mtd->eb_size;
```

Even though this chip has a MTD driver, i do not think write cycles are a concern and that is why the erase block is zero. so my questions are the following:

1. Should i modify the driver to give the chip an erase block size so the utilities work correctly? If so what size?
2. Should i modify `libmtd` to ignore the zero erase block size? If so what should i set the `eb_cnt` to?
3. Is there a better way to read and write data to the MTD device?

Additional Notes:

1. Stability is more important than optimal performance in my situation
2. I tried to do an `echo test > /dev/mtdblock0` and `cat /dev/mtdblock0` and got nothing but garbage

**Update 10/20**
Changed the erase block size to 1 in the driver (I desired to change it to 4000, but i was unsure about units). MTD Utils no longer throws the exception given before.

```
~# mtdinfo
Count of MTD devices:           1
Present MTD devices:            mtd0
Sysfs interface supported:      yes
```

However ubiformat does fail:

```
~# ubiformat /dev/mtd0
ubiformat: mtd0 (ram), size 131072 bytes (128.0 KiB), 131072 eraseblocks of 
1 bytes, min. I/O size 1 bytes
libscan: scanning eraseblock 0 --  0 % complete  libmtd: error!: bad offset 
0 or length 64, mtd0 eraseblock size is 1
ubiformat: error!: failed to scan mtd0 (/dev/mtd0)
```

**Update #2 10/20**
Unfortunately setting the erase block size to 4000 (actually 0x4000) cause the kernel to crash after running ubiformat

```
~# ubiformat /dev/mtd0
ubiformat: mtd0 (ram), size 131072 bytes (128.0 KiB), 8 eraseblocks of 16384 
bytes (16.0 KiB), min. I/O size 1 bytes
libscan: scanning erasebUnable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 
virtual address 00000000
libscanpgd = 8cc6c000te
libscan: scanning eras[00000000] *pgd=8cbbb835, *pte=00000000, *ppte=00000000
libscan: scanning eInternal error: Oops: 80000007 [#1] PREEMPT SMP ARM
```

**Update 10/23**
I tried to format the drive normally with fdisk, but seem to be getting errors regarding the lack of cylinders:

```
:~# fdisk  /dev/mtdblock0
...
Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/mtdblock0: 0 MB, 131072 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 0 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
      Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks  Id System
Command (m for help): n
Unknown value(s) for: cylinders (settable in the extra functions menu)
```

Comment: Unless you're hoping for a special recognition of 0 as "does not apply" logically the actual erase size would be the memory's addressable width - on most architectures 1 byte.   However, the SLRAM driver seems to use its block size which is 4k, probably following from an a MMU pagesize.

Comment: I'll modify the driver to set the erase block size to 4K and report back what happens.

Comment: +1 to @ChrisStratton idea, was about to write that 4K sounds plausible, though I’m not sure why it uses that kind of interface in the first place.

Comment: *"The existing device driver for the SRAM chip registers the device as a MTD."*  -- That sounds misguided, i.e. the wrong approach.  The last time I did a driver for (battery-backed) SRAM, I just wrote a simple ram-disk driver.

Comment: @0andriy yeah it seems odd. The driver is in the Linux mainline ([23K256](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/mtd/devices/mchp23k256.c)) and the commit messages acknowledge that it should have an erase block size of zero.

Comment: @sawdust writing a RAM driver is a good backup. I am just hoping that by using a driver in Linux mainline, I'll get continued support.

Comment: If erase block is meaningless and it is just a sram chip (did i get it right?) What is the point of using mtd based file system? Could you format it with fat or ext4? Or there is no way to do this for mtd device in linux?

Comment: Looks like it is possible ...

Comment: @AlexHoppus just tried this, `fdisk` fails due to the devices having zero cylinders and `parted` is failing in a way i cannot seem to figure out. Both of these were used on mtdblock0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an underlying hardware problem that once fixed allowed for data to be written and read from the `/dev/mtdblock0` device. This was verified by using `echo TEST > /dev/mtdblock0` to write and `cat /dev/mtdblock` to read.

Here is a summary of the other bugs found while researching this problem

1. If the chip is malfunctioning the 23K256 driver will still produce the correct amount of output from a `cat /dev/mtdblock0` call. The output will be all the same, while the actual uninitialized chip output will be random.
2. All applications using `libmtd`, including all of the `mtd-utils`, will error when dealing with a MTD devices with erase block size of zero.
3. Artificially setting the SRAM erase block size to 0x4000 in the driver *may* fix this problem. Erase size of 1 was unacceptable.
4. `fdisk` will error due to cylinder size being 0 (may be possible to get around using expert mode)